# SQLITE selecting distinct entries that are less than 1 minute old

Tags: sqlite

I'm making a flight tracking map that will need to pull live data from a sql lite db. I'm currently just using the sqlite executable to navigate the db and understand how to interact with it. Each aircraft is identified by a unique hex_ident. I want to get a list of all aircraft that have sent out a signal in the last minute as a way of identifying which aircraft are actually active right now. I tried

```
select distinct hex_ident, parsed_time 
from squitters 
where parsed_time >= Datetime('now','-1 minute')
```

I expected a list of 4 or 5 hex_idents only but I'm just getting a list of every entry (today's entries only) and some are outside the 1 minute bound. I'm new to sql so I don't really know how to do this yet. Here's what each entry looks like. The table is called squitters.

```
{
"message_type":"MSG",
"transmission_type":8,
"session_id":"111",
"aircraft_id":"11111",
"hex_ident":"A1B4FE",
"flight_id":"111111",
"generated_date":"2021/02/12",
"generated_time":"14:50:42.403",
"logged_date":"2021/02/12",
"logged_time":"14:50:42.385",
"callsign":"",
"altitude":"",
"ground_speed":"",
"track":"",
"lat":"",
"lon":"",
"vertical_rate":"",
"squawk":"",
"alert":"",
"emergency":"",
"spi":"",
"is_on_ground":0,
"parsed_time":"2021-02-12T19:50:42.413746"
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove `'T'` from the value of `parsed_time` or use `datetime()` for it also to make the comparison work:

```
where datetime(parsed_time) >= datetime('now', '-1 minute')
```

Note that `datetime()` function does not take into account microseconds, so if you need 100% accuracy, you must put them in the code with concatenation:

```
where replace(parsed_time, 'T', ' ') >= 
      datetime('now', '-1 minute') || substr(parsed_time, instr(parsed_time, '.'))
```

Comment: Okay that works. Still trying to get DISTINCT to work. Is it because it's looking for a distinct hex_ident AND timestamp? Which won't exist? edit: that was it

Comment: @LeonJones DISTINCT returns distinct combinations of hex_ident and parsed_time.